# Installing python packages in google colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, setup.py

I wanted to install a package in Google Colab. I tried uploading the `setup.py` to my drive but with no luck.

The package can be found [here](http://sdpa.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Just moving setup.py around doesn't help you at all, it just contains instructions on setting up the package.

For that particular package (SDPA-P), I would otherwise advise to try to `!pip install` the tarball you can download via https://sourceforge.net/projects/sdpa/files/sdpa-p/sdpap-0.2.1.tar.gz/download but it seems it relies on hard-coded paths:

```
# pip install sdpap-0.2.1.tar.gz
Processing ./sdpap-0.2.1.tar.gz
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-req-build-3nmuqm1l/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
          [line.split('=') for line in open(SDPA_MAKEINC).readlines()])
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/sdpa/sdpa.7.3.1/etc/make.inc'
      [end of output]
```

Installing that particular package will likely require quite some work; your best bet could be to build a binary wheel package out of it, and install that in Colab... but again, it'll be quite some work.

Comment: hi there - many thanks for clearing this important topic. Awesome:: thank your for showing the code ...!pip install the tarball you can download via